# Procedures for fault-tolerant nondestructive logical measurements

Tags: error-correction, resource-request, fault-tolerance

Definition 2 on page 20 in Daniel Gottesman's [An Introduction to Quantum Error Correction and Fault-Tolerant Quantum Computation](https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.2557) states that a nondestructive logical measurement procedure is fault tolerant if

> the total number of errors in the incoming state and measurement
> gadget is at most t, then we should get the same result out of the real gadget as
> if we had performed ideal decoding on the incoming state and measured the decoded qubit.

Are there procedures known that satisfy this definition for arbitrary distance?

I am aware of the distance 3 procedure in section 7.4 of [Quantum accuracy threshold for concatenated distance-3 codes](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0504218). It is straightforward to extend this to higher distance.

I am also aware of the code specific measurement procedures in section 10 of [Short Shor-style syndrome sequences](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.05051).